# How to Zero Pad Month and Day in R

Tags: r

I've read-in an excel file with dates formatted as `m/d/yyyy`, which R is reading as a factor. Trying the below returns all `NA`:

```
strptime(tvMid$calendar_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It appears I need to zero pad the `m` and/or `d` conditionally, based-on whether it is a single-digit month or day. What is the best approach to add these zeroes?

Comment: What happens if you use `readr::read_csv()` instead? And, if the file is in `m/d/yyyy` format what made you think specifying the format as `%Y-%m-%d` would work?

Comment: Depending on what you use to read the Excel file—you didn't say—you might have an option for setting the column type or preventing characters from being read as factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.frame(
  calendar_date = "5/13/2018"
) -> tvMid

strptime(tvMid$calendar_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
## [1] "2018-05-13 EDT"
```